# best strategy to install PandocAgda which requires base < 4.7 when ghc 7.8.3 is installed

Tags: haskell, cabal

Upon `cabal install` - ation of `PandocAgda`, i get

> rejecting: base-4.7.0.1/installed-df2... (conflict: PandocAgda =>
>   base>=4.2 && <4.7)

I have on my machine

> ~ ❯❯❯ ghc --version
>   The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System,
>   version 7.8.3

Is base tied to ghc version ?

What is the cleanest way to have PandocAgda installed ?

Answer (score 2):

All of the releases of `PandocAgda` seem to have `< 4.7` set on base. You can try using the `--allow-newer` flag to `cabal` and see if that finds a build plan that's compatible with 7.8.3.